# Showing that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}\sin(\sqrt{x})$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, absolute-continuity

This is an old qualifying exam problem, and I'm wondering if my proof is correct. (I'm still not too comfortable with absolute continuity.)

We know that
$$f'(x) = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{2}$$
and this is defined for all $x \in (0,1].$

We want to check that $f'(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1].$ First, note that for any $\epsilon > 0,$ we have that $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[\epsilon,1].$ Indeed, for any $x \in [\epsilon,1],$ we know that
$$ |f'(x)| =  \frac{1}{2}|x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sin(\sqrt{x}) + \cos(\sqrt{x})| \leq \frac{1}{2}(|x|^{-\frac{1}{2}} + 1) \leq \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon^{-\frac{1}{2}}+1).$$
In particular, $f(x)$ is absolutely continuous on $[\epsilon,1],$ so $f'(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[\epsilon,1].$

Next, note that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f'(x)\,dx
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \int_\epsilon^1 f'(x) \, dx \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} (f(1) - f(\epsilon)) \\
&= \sin{1} - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \sqrt{\epsilon}\sin(\sqrt\epsilon).
\end{align*}
But by L'Hospital,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \sqrt{\epsilon}\sin(\sqrt\epsilon)
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \frac{\frac{\cos(\sqrt{\epsilon})}{2\sqrt{\epsilon}}}{\frac{-1}{2\epsilon^{3/2}}} \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} -\epsilon\cos(\sqrt{\epsilon})\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$\int_0^1 f'(x) \, dx = \sin{1} < \infty,$$
and so $f'(x)$ is integrable on $[0,1].$

By the same procedure as above, we know that
$$\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt = f(x) = f(x) - f(0),$$
and so this implies that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

I feel like I'm only using the defintion of absolute continuity, and basic facts about integration, which is why I was wondering if I didn't make any errors.

Comment: The proof of $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \sqrt{\epsilon}\sin(\sqrt\epsilon) = 0$ can be simplified. There is no need to use L'H since $\sin(\sqrt\epsilon)$ is bounded and $\sqrt{\epsilon} \to 0$. (Use Sandwich theorem.)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Right, I completely missed that. My brain just autopiloted to L'H.

Comment: It's easy to see that $f'(x)$ can be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1]$, hence it is bounded. It follows that $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[0,1]$, and therefore absolutely continuous.